# SliverChildBuilderDelegate - reverse method

Tags: list, flutter, dart, reverse, flutter-sliver

Is there a `reverse` option for a `SliverList` like there is for `ListView.builder`?

I can see that the `CustomScrollView` has a `reverse` method but that doesn't help for what I'm looking for.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: @AdrianMurray , he need to reverse the `SliverList` only. Not the entire `CustomScrollView` slivers.  @tom-osullivan Did you resolve this?

Comment: In the end to fix this I reversed the list itself instead of reversing the slivers

Answer (score 2):

Since `SliverList` does not have a a `reverse` option or parameter, you'll have to *calculate the reversed index* by hand inside the `SliverChildDelegate` that's used to create the children. This would only be possible if you know the length of the list you are building.

Given you have a `List`, you can calculate the reversed index from `SliverChildDelegate.builder`'s index.

```dart
(BuildContext context, int index) {
  final reversedIndex = items.length - index - 1;
  ...
}
```

Here is what it looks with a `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`:

```dart
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (BuildContext context, int index) {
      final reversedIndex = items.length - index - 1;
      return MyWidget(items[reversedIndex]);
    },
    childCount: items.length,
  ),
);
```

Comment: I could not find any obvious answer at first, hopefully this will help someone in the future. :-)